# inncorrect signature: void put(OpportunityLineItem) from the type Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>

Tags: apex, map

I have this below code which is throwing error. Can anyone help what is going wrong.

Error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(OpportunityLineItem) from the type Map

Code

```
Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> mapOli = new Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> ();
for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule sch: lstLineItemSchedule) {
    If(mapOli.get(sch.OpportunityLineItemId) == null) {
        Decimal oliUniPrice = oliIDToSalesPriceMap.get(sch.OpportunityLineItemId);
        mapOli.put(new OpportunityLineItem(Id=sch.Id,UnitPrice =oliUniPrice));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A [`Map.put()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) expects a `<key, value>` pair whenever you add an element in it. The signature for the method is: `public Object put(Object key, Object value)`.

In your case, you are missing the `key` to be added in the Map and thus the error.

```
mapOli.put(new OpportunityLineItem(Id=oLisch.Id,UnitPrice =oliUniPrice));
```

You will need to change this to as below:

```
mapOli.put(<key- whatever you choose>, new OpportunityLineItem(Id=oLisch.Id,UnitPrice =oliUniPrice));
```